# Forking interactive bash from bash script

Tags: bash, fork

I am trying to fork interactive bash from bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -c 'bash -i -l' &
```

After running above script process 'bash -i -l' hits 100% CPU usage.
What is the reason for such behaviour?

I am testing this on Fedora 16.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, but what is the purpose of the `bash -c` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. Note this is equivalent to running:

`bash -c "bash -c 'bash -i -l' &"`

At your command prompt. I got the same result just running:

`bash -c "bash -i &"`

Pretty sure whats happening is the Bash is polling trying to get access to the controlling terminal (because its trying to be interactive), but its not allowed (becuase its a background process). I tried running `bash -c 'strace -o bash_trace.txt bash -i &'`. Its doing this in a loop:

```
...
    rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
kill(0, SIGTTIN)                        = 0
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(255, TIOCGPGRP, [9964])           = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
kill(0, SIGTTIN)                        = 0
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(255, TIOCGPGRP, [9964])           = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
kill(0, SIGTTIN)                        = 0
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
...
```

Processes get SIGTTIN when they try to access the controlling terminal but they are backgrounded - http://www.lindevdoc.org/wiki/SIGTTIN. Whether the correct behavior to spin about like this, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, it is good lead. Original problem that I am trying to trace is following: in one java thread exec "bash -c 'bash -i -l' 2>&1" and it works fine. If I do same exec in second java thread while first is running I got high CPU load and no response from second bash. I will introduce logging that you purpose to see if it is same case like above. Thanks again.